# Increase test coverage in AngularJS controller with no functions

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I'm new to this, so if any of you guys could help!
I'm trying to write a test case for controller with no function, how would I do that to bring up the coverage.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('xyz').controller('ThisOne',function(){
        var vm = this;
        vm.add = 'abc';
        vm.additional='sde';
    });
})();
```

I did `describe`, `beforeEach`, controller in spec.js, but how to get `vm.add` and additional stuff to be covered?

Comment: What test framework/library do you use?

Comment: Using AngularJS (Jasmine for testing)